# Finding Symantec distrusted certificates

Tags: bash, openssl, certificate, symantec

I need to find Symantec certificates that are being distrusted by Google.

I have got list of roots in .pem format from here: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/data/ssl/symantec/README.md?g=0

On the server i have got access to .crt files that I need to check if it is affected or not.

Is there a way to do this in Bash using openssl command?

Thank you,